# Get selected Item from wxtreeCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

How should you get the item selected in `wxTreeCtrl`? I bind the method to the activated item like this:

```
 self.tree.Bind (wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnAdd, id=10)
```

And in the method `OnAdd` I try to get the item:

```
    def OnAdd(self, event):
        item =  event.GetItem()
```

But it gives error that event has no `GetItem()` method. Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I had assigned a button event to process selected item.
So that's why the event had not item attached to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the callback incorrectly. You currently do:

```
self.Bind (wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnAdd, id=10)
```

But the 3rd parameter is the `source`; `id` is the 4th parameter. So, change it to this:

```
self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, size=(200,100)) # Or however you defined it
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnAdd, self.tree, id=10)
```

This way, the `event` argument you will get in your `OnAdd` function will be the `tree` instance, which will have the `GetItem` method available.

Full example:

```
import wx

class TreeExample(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Tree Example', size=(200, 130))
        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, size=(200, 100))

        root = self.tree.AddRoot('root')
        for item in ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']:
            self.tree.AppendItem(root, item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree)
        self.tree.Expand(root)

    def OnActivated(self, evt):
        print 'Double clicked on', self.tree.GetItemText(evt.GetItem())

app = wx.PySimpleApp(None)
TreeExample().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @Arash: it works for me :). I added a full example for you to try out.

Comment: Thanks for update.It runs for me as well as an example.but in my original code when I made the exact changes still gives me error.That why the headache

Comment: `self.tree` should of course be your `TreeCtrl` instance... did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

just my 2cents:

I've been looking for the same solution with C++/wxWidgets for 2 days.

I found a really good working example:

1. I use Codeblocks with wxSmith(RAD tool). Ubuntu Bionic
2. Ssh from windows && export display && Codeblocks

And here's the code for this specific Event...

```
void test12052019Frame::OnTreeCtrl1ItemActivated(wxTreeEvent& event)
{
//TreeCtrl1 is my tree
//when I click on any option of my tree
//it activates a wxMessageBox with the label
//of the option selected...
//just let go your imagination :)
//A youtube video will follow.

wxString thelabel;
wxTreeItemId test3;

test3 = TreeCtrl1->GetSelection();//id of the item selected
thelabel = TreeCtrl1->GetItemText(test3);//extract associated text

wxMessageBox(thelabel); //shazam !


}
```

[Working example on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmBLdZRObO8)